# PRINTING A TEXTFILE USING C# THRU LPT1 PORT and network printer for fastprinting

Tags: printing, text-files

I have to print a text file created using  Crystal Report import . now i Hve to print it directly to LPT1 port for fast dotmatrix printing . I used the below code, nothing is working . Any help would be greatly apprecialtable .

### 1.System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Print", @"\D:LPT1" +" "+ txtFilepath);

1. System.Diagnostics.Process printProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo PrintStartInfo = new ystem.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("Print.exe");

string STRARGS = txtFilepath + " " + "/D:LPT1"; 
PrintStartInfo.Arguments = STRARGS;
printProcess.StartInfo = PrintStartInfo;
printProcess.Start();

### printProcess.WaitForExit();

### 3.System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Print", txtFilepath);

Please help me

Regards,
Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. It will solve your problem.

[How to Send Raw Data to Printer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

Comment: hi Asifabbas , its a Preformated files can i use this code to print the file for fast printing ..without changing the alignment ...

Comment: It should work because it send raw data to printer including printer codes. The text file created by Crystal Report contains printer codes for bold/italics, fonts size etc. Have u tried to use Printer Font i.e. Draft, Courier directly in Crystal Report. This will send fast character based report without having to generate text file.